# query the same table twice to get different numbers in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server, Table1 has customer requests, table2 has a resolution code (so we can see why customers are writing in, and what we did to resolve their issue).  Sometimes reps forget to add the resolution code, so I'm trying to run a query to tell me the name of each rep, how many closed issues are missing a resolution code, how many issues did they close in total, and what's their % of closed issues versus closed issues without a resolution code.  For example:

```
Agent Name | Missing Resolution Codes | Total issues closed | % of 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Mary       |             12           |         120         | 10.00%
Bob        |              8           |         704         |  1.14%
```

The query to show missing resolution codes works great.  The query to show total issues closed works great.  Whenever I try to combine them, I either get this:

(with UNION)

```
Mary |  12
Mary | 120
Bob  |   8
Bob  | 704
```

or if I try `from (select...) t1, (select...) t2`, I get this:

```
Mary | 12 | 120
Mary | 12 | 704
Bob  |  8 | 120
Bob  |  8 | 704
```

If I add a Group By at the end, I get all kinds of errors.

The two queries on their own are as follows:

Missing resolution code:

```
select i.assigned_to, count(i.assigned_to)
from customer_issues as i
left join resolution_codes as r on i.issue_ID = r.issue_ID
where r.issue_id is null
and i.status='closed'
group by i.assigned_to
```

Total closed issues:

```
select assigned_to, count(assigned_to)
from customer_issues
where status='closed'
group by assigned_to
```

Appreciate any help you can provide!

EDIT: Just to clarify, the resolution codes are in a different table because one customer issue could contain several problems and several solutions.  So while the customer_issues table does have an indicator that the issue itself is closed, the resolution_codes table shows the different problems the customer had, which ones we could solve, which ones we couldn't, etc.

Comment: Your desired output is resolution count in one field and closed in another? Could do `SELECT t1.name,.... from (select...) t1 JOIN (select...) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name`

Comment: Use your second approach, and relate t1 and t2 on assigned_to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.assigned_to, t1.missing, t2.total from 
( 
select i.assigned_to as assigned_to, count(i.assigned_to) as missing
from customer_issues as i
left join resolution_codes as r on i.issue_ID = r.issue_ID
where r.issue_id is null
and i.status='closed'
group by i.assigned_to
) t1 INNER JOIN
(
select assigned_to, count(assigned_to) as total
from customer_issues
where status='closed'
group by assigned_to
) t2
ON t1.assigned_to=t2.assigned_to
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!  It was the "where t1.assigned_to=t2.assigned_to" that was missing.

Comment: While this works, it's advisable to avoid deprecated syntax (creating a cross join with a comma separated list of tables and constraining in the  `WHERE` clause has been out of standard for a long while, but works fine). More importantly, the whole thing could be done in one query, which would improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only difference between the two queries seems to be the left join and null filter you can do it all in one query.

This should work I think:

```
;with source as (
   select 
        i.assigned_to as [Agent Name], 
        count(r.issue_id) as [Resolution Codes], 
        count(i.assigned_to) as [Total issues closed]
    from customer_issues as i
    left join resolution_codes as r on i.issue_ID = r.issue_ID
    where i.status='closed'
    group by i.assigned_to
)

select 
    [Agent Name], 
    [Total issues closed]-[Resolution Codes] as [Missing Resolution Codes],
    [Total issues closed],
    ([Total issues closed]-[Resolution Codes])*100.0/[Total issues closed] as [% of]
from source;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6124/2)

Comment: When I try this, I get a devide by zero error.  When I remove the vision part, I can see why.  The Agent name of "NULL" shows -335 under missing resolution codes, and 0 for total issues closed.  Adding an "assigned_to is not null" seems to have solved that as well.

Comment: @SpiceWeasel It's quite possible that I missed something as I guessed a bit about your tables, and didn't have any good data to test with. I don't see why it would do a zero division though, but if you say it does I believe you. Did you try the code in the fiddle or the one above? I changed it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated)

Evidently, the absence of a resolution code is not reflected anywhere in table `customer_issues`, but only in the absence of any row in `resolution_codes` corresponding to a given issue.  That seems a little hinky, but it may be sensible in the larger scheme of things.  Anyway, you can perform a single aggregate query to collect all the stats you need in one go, and then compute all your derived statistics from the results.

It is useful to perform the aggregate query as an inline view, so as to more easily (and less verbosely) reuse the two aggregate columns:

```
select
  agg.assigned_to,
  agg.total_closed,
  (agg.total_closed - agg.with_code) as without_code,
  ((agg.total_closed - agg.with_code) / cast(agg.total_closed as float)) as "% without"
FROM (
    select
      ci.assigned_to,
      count(*) as total_closed,
      count(rc.issue_id) as with_code
    from customer_issues ci
      left join resolution_codes rc on ci.issue_ID = rc.issue_ID
    where ci.status='closed'
    group by ci.assigned_to
  ) agg
  ;
```

Comment: I like the way you think, but when I try that query, all I get a list of assigned_to and total_closed.  The without_code and % without are all zeros.  These tables were setup over a decade ago, so I assume I will still need to use a join in this case?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel, Hmm.  Probably I made an incorrect assumption about the structure of your data, as summed up in my assertion that "A missing resolution code must manifest as `customer_issues.issue_ID IS NULL`".  If instead missing resolution codes manifest only in the absence of rows from table `resolution_codes` then yes, you do need a join.  I have updated my answer to assume this case.

Comment: Also, I added some parentheses and switched to qualified names, though I don't think either was necessary.